# client / server program in c++ problem

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock2

I have created a client and server program in c++ based i=on windows sockets.
I have some problem that when i execute the program no message appears on the server end and after that the program exits.Data is sending to server but it is not responding back.

i am pasting my code below

```
****Server code
===========****

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT        "27015" 
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN      512
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    WSADATA wsdata;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsdata);
    if(result != 0){
        printf("%s","Unable to initilize windows socket\n");
        getch();
        return 1;
    }
    struct addrinfo *addrResult = NULL,hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof (hints));

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    result = getaddrinfo(NULL,DEFAULT_PORT,&hints,&addrResult);
    if(result != 0){
        printf("%s","Error in getaddrInfo");
        getch();
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    listenSocket = socket(addrResult->ai_family,addrResult->ai_socktype,addrResult->ai_protocol);
    if(listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("%s","Error in creating socket object\n");
        getch();
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    service.sin_port = htons(27015);

    if( bind(listenSocket,addrResult->ai_addr,
        (int)addrResult->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    //if(bind(listenSocket,(SOCKADDR*) &service,
    //  sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR){

        printf("bind failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        getch();
        return 1;

    }
    freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
    if(listen(listenSocket,SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        printf("%s","Error in listening socket");
        getch();
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    SOCKET clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    clientSocket = accept((listenSocket,NULL,NULL);
    if(clientSocket ==  INVALID_SOCKET){
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iRecvResult, iSendResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    do{
        iRecvResult = 0;
        iSendResult = 0;
        iRecvResult = recv(clientSocket,recvbuf,recvbuflen,0);
        if(iRecvResult > 0){
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iRecvResult);
            getch();
            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(clientSocket, recvbuf, iRecvResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(clientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iRecvResult == 0){
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    }while(iRecvResult > 0);
  getch();
  return 0;
}


**client code
============**


#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT        "27015" 
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN      512
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main(){
    WSADATA wsdata;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsdata);
    struct addrinfo *addrResult = NULL,hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof (hints));
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    int result = 0;
    if(getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1",DEFAULT_PORT,
        &hints,&addrResult)){
            printf("%s","Error in getaddrInfo\n");
            WSACleanup();
            getch();
            return 1;
    }
    SOCKET connectingSocket = INVALID_SOCKET; 
    connectingSocket = socket(addrResult->ai_family,addrResult->ai_socktype,
        addrResult->ai_protocol);
    if(connectingSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("%s","Error in creating socket\n");
        freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
        WSACleanup();
        getch();
        return 1;
    }

        if(connect(connectingSocket,addrResult->ai_addr, (int)addrResult->ai_addrlen) != 0){
        closesocket(connectingSocket);
        connectingSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        WSACleanup();

    }
    freeaddrinfo(addrResult);

    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

    int iResult;

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(connectingSocket, sendbuf, (int) strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(connectingSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection for sending since no more data will be sent
    // the client can still use the connectingSocket for receiving data
    iResult = shutdown(connectingSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(connectingSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive data until the server closes the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(connectingSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    } while (iResult > 0);




    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Your help is highly appreciated it is not working on my n=machine some people are saying that this code is working well on their machines. I have used visual studio 2005 to develop this and my OS is windows 7.

Comment: or if u have any sample code in c++ that is doing the same thing can you people give it to me for reference.So that i will check where i am wrong.

Comment: It's not clear from your explanation what exactly you see on the server side. Does the server code ever reach the receiving loop? If so, what does it print (it has to print something on all execution paths)? If not, where does it exit?

Comment: Is this any different from the question you asked yesterday?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009587/problem-in-accepting-connection-from-client-socket-programming-in-vc-net

Comment: @user434507:: the server waits for some client to connect to it when the client sends the data the prompt message on the client id bytes sent:14 connection closing and nothing appears on the server side.

Comment: @Duck:: it is exactly the same question but it is not working on my end that's why i have pasted the same question go get some valuable idea that can solve my problem.

Comment: @Abdul, you seem to violate an important programming principle DRY - don't repeat yourself :) you see - this copy-pasted topic still has that error "accept((" which had been fixed already in original topic

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sample code at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx